# Why some concepts of java needs to use wrapper class instead of primitive datatypes

Tags: java, primitive-types

Please explain that what is the logic behind the concept to introduce java wrapper class..? What is the problem with primitive datatypes, that some concepts like collection only uses wrapper class instead of primitive data type..? Also need explanation of memory level concepts if we use wrapper class

Comment: @Progman: my answer is more advanced and more completely than the one you found. Second: the question you’ve linked is closed.

Answer (score 0):

A wrapper class in context of data types brings more convenience to you as developer and resolve some problems:

1. A wrapper class includes help methods to especially convert a data type to another. E.g.
   `Integer digit = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);`

because `args[0]` is always a String.

Or some helping methods like this: `Character.isUpperCase(char);`

2. A wrapper class includes useful constants like `MIN_VALUE` and `MAX_VALUE`.
3. `BigDecimal` must be used instead of `float` or `double`, if the accuracy after decimal point  is important. The data types `float` and `double` can’t provide precision at general.
4. Generics can only be used with classes (with reference types as generic type argument) . E.g. `List<int>` is impossible, but `List<Integer>`.

My answer is probably not completely :-).